# Python put variables in text

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have a question.

How can I put global variables of a lambda application (AWS) in a text (String) in the Python code?

```
def send_email(sender, recipient, aws_region, subject):
   SENDER = sender
   RECIPIENT = recipient
   AWS_REGION = aws_region
   SUBJECT = subject
   BODY_TEXT = ""
   BODY_HTML = """<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
        <h1>${os.environ['FUNCTION_NAME']} (Error)</h1>
       <p>Service STOMP in AMQ Server in ${os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']} not respond.</p>
        <br><br><br>
        <p>Automatic service:</p>
        <p>Lambda function: ${os.environ['FUNCTION_NAME']}</p>
        <p>AMQ IPs: ${os.environ['AWS_LB']}</p>
   </body>
   </html>
             """
   CHARSET = "UTF-8"
```

and now the result is

```
${os.environ['FUNCTION_NAME']} (Error)
Service STOMP in AMQ Server in ${os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']} not respond.


Automatic service:
Lambda function: ${os.environ['FUNCTION_NAME']}
AMQ IPs: ${os.environ['AWS_LB']}
```

but I want

```
text (Error)
Service STOMP in AMQ Server in dev not respond.


Automatic service:
Lambda function: function_name
AMQ IPs: ips
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're just writing the name of the variables you want to a string literal e.g. `os.environ['FUNCTION_NAME']` as a string and not the value that you would expect returned if you ran this sequence of characters within a Python script/session.

You can have Python interpolate variable values into a string by making use of f strings as introduced in version 3.6 - [link to f string docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

In short you can simply add the character `f` before the opening quotation marks during assignment of a string value and any code contained within curly braces will be ran, and the return/referenced value inserted into the string at that position.

The code from your original question could look like this if you wish to use f strings.

```py
def send_email(sender, recipient, aws_region, subject):
   SENDER = sender
   RECIPIENT = recipient
   AWS_REGION = aws_region
   SUBJECT = subject
   BODY_TEXT = ""
   BODY_HTML = f"""<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
        <h1>{os.environ['FUNCTION_NAME']} (Error)</h1>
       <p>Service STOMP in AMQ Server in {os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']} not respond.</p>
        <br><br><br>
        <p>Automatic service:</p>
        <p>Lambda function: {os.environ['FUNCTION_NAME']}</p>
        <p>AMQ IPs: {os.environ['AWS_LB']}</p>
   </body>
   </html>
             """
   CHARSET = "UTF-8"
```

Comment: This solutions is working when you put only a "text" but not with """text""". But thanks for the answer, I'm going to remove the quotation marks anyway

Comment: Triple-quoted f-strings should work perfectly well, as per the [PEP says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#triple-quoted-f-strings). Have you checked if there's any typo or mistake somewhere?